# meaning of '+='

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, operators

I'm confused with the syntax of C#: what is the use of "+="?

Comment: Please learn the meaning of the tags field.

Comment: Please also learn to spell and use grammar.

Comment: Hi, this site can be a little more fussy than your usual forums but the effort put in to ask effective questions is worth it. You get more mileage out from here if you type in complete English, provide specific context to your question, and provide examples.

Comment: Any more edits, and this question will have less than 5 words (It could be asked in less than 5 words) :D

Answer (score 30):

The `+=` syntax can be used in different ways:

```
SomeEvent += EventHandler;
```

Adds a handler to an event.

---

```
SomeVariable += 3;
```

Is equivalent to

```
SomeVariable = SomeVariable + 3;
```

Comment: Good answer.  I would have spaced on the event handler aspect of this operator, despite knowing better.

Comment: The event handler aspect is pretty much identical to the other aspects; all that's happening there is that the event/delegate object overrides the + operator.

a += b is simply syntactic sugar for a = a + b. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx, which states "Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded."

Comment: @Technophile: Wrong.  When outside the class (or always in C# 4.0), `instance.Event += handler` compiles to `instance.add_Event(handler);`

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for the clarification. They're conceptually identical, I had just misremembered the implementation.

Comment: @Technophile: They're not entirely conceptually identical.  In fact, it's a (subtle) breaking change: http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2010/03/18/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-iii-breaking-changes.aspx

Comment: On an event, it calls the add method associated with the event.  On a delegate field, however, it decomposed to SomeDelegate = SomeDelegate + AnotherDelegate and just concatenates the invocation lists.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a compound operator. They are common to all languages I can thing of: Javascript, C, Java, PHP, .net, GL.

Like everyone has said, is a shortened version of `value = value + 3`.

There are multiple reasons for its use. Most obviously it's quicker to write, easier to read and faster to spot errors with.

Most importantly, a compound operator is specifically designed not to require as much computation as the equivalent `value = value + 3`. I'm not totally sure why but the evidence is paramount.

Simply create a loop, looping for say 5,000,000 adding a value as you proceed. In two test cases, I know personally from Actionscript, there is roughly a 60% speed increase with compound operators.

---

You also have the equivalent:

`+=`:  addition

`-=`:  subtraction

`/=`:  multiplication

`*=`:  multplication

`%=`:  modulus

and the less obvious:

`++`:  Plus one

`--`:  Minus one

Comment: And the full list of compound assignment operators is here: `x += y 

x -= y 

x *= y 

x /= y 

x %= y 

x &= y 

x |= y 

x ^= y 

x <<= y 

x >>= y`

Copied from [MSDN: C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

```
a += 3
```

is the same as

```
a = a + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, it is not necessarily always equivalent.

for ordinary variables, `a+=a` is, indeed, equivalent to `a=a+a`, and shorter!. For the odd variable which changes its state, not so much.